# Core Plot CPLineStyle compile error on readonly property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Trying to build Core Plot and use CPLineStyle I get a compile error from this code...

```
CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
```

error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

The property is @synthesize'd and while it's declared

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) CPColor *lineColor;
```

in the header it is redeclared in a category for the class as

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) CPColor *lineColor;
```

The compiler doesn't seem to know about the redeclaration of the property. What's wrong here?

Gonzalo

Comment: The properties are intended to have scope only in the CPLineStyle implementation file. Should use CPMutableLineStyle instead.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this way this worked for me ...

```
CPMutableLineStyle *plotlineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
plotlineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor whiteColor];
plotlineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
```

then apply this style to axis or whatever similar you can do for textstyle using CPMutableTextStyle..

Answer (score 0):

You need CPTMutableLineStyle (instead of CPLineStyle).

So, change:

```
CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
```

To:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
```